# Google Analytics Event firing too often

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have a page setup with the following GA JavaScript on the page to track pageviews

```
           ga('create', 'UA-xxxx-xxx', 'auto');
                ga('send', 'pageview', location.pathname);
```

I also have the following JavaScript within document.ready to track an Event

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[type="submit"]', function () {
    if (typeof (ga) !== 'undefined') {
        ga('send', 'event', 'Your Details', 'Save Address Change');
    }
});
```

Within all development and test environments, the code fires only when it should (the form contains only ONE button) but in LIVE, the Event is almost in line with the pageview number (and the backend data confirms that the button has not been pressed as it is logged in the SQL database as it fires an INSERT statement). When I attempt to debug the JS, the event does NOT fire

Is there any way the pageview event on my form could then be triggering the event? Caching?

Using the secondary dimensions, I cannot find any data that tells me what or who is triggering this event on almost every pageview. All it confirms is that this is not isolated to one browser

Comment: first of all `typeof (ga) != 'undefined'` instead of `!==`

Answer (score 0):

The code looks like it would operate the way you would hope, so there must be something else going on... This isn't particularly an answer as much as it is other things to check that may lead to an answer:

- How many Unique Events vs. Total Events are occurring for "Your Details"?
- Are there any other submit buttons elsewhere on the page (search, subscribe, etc)?
- Any chance you're loading your tracking script (where the event listener is) more than once?
- How about spam bots? Have you noticed many server-side crawlers? This wouldn't be caused by "ghost" spambots, so check for `Full Referrer` as a secondary dimension.
- Does this appear on both your unfiltered and filtered views?
- Are any other core metrics (users, sessions, pageviews, *bounce rate*) in your reports odd?
- Create a segment for just users who have triggered this event and look through all of your other reports. Are they following a typical funnel/path that you would expect?
- Check the User Explorer to see if you can find a specific user who triggered the event. What else did they do? Does it look like a normal users?

  - You could add a custom dimension of Client ID and parse the GA cookie to track which CIDs are triggering the event (it would help you find them in the User Explorer).
- Other custom dimensions that could help you get more context clues: Timestamp, Hit ID (random ID assigned to every individual hit), PHP Referrer.
- The long shot: any chance some other script is triggering a click on that button?

I hope something here helps you.